# How can I write backslash "\" in text?

Tags: macros

I want to show '\' in final pdf file, not as a command to latex, but as a text '\' itself. How can I do this?

Comment: `\textbackslash`

Comment: Also, `\string\ ` or `\string\macroname`, with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` activated.